# CreateProcess error=0, The operation completed successfully

Tags: java, windows

As background:  this is a Java SE desktop program that at one point is required to spawn another Java process.  It does this by assembling the command line to spawn and calling

```
// actual code has this inside a try-catch block for IOException
process = new ProcessBuilder(list_of_the_java_command_strings)
               .directory(a_different_working_directory)
               .inheritIO()
               .redirectError(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.PIPE)
               .start();
```

(Later it will do `process.getErrorStream()` for the reading end of the pipe, but I don't believe that comes into play here.)

The spawned executable, stored in the first String in `list_of_the_java_command_strings`, is determined by `System.getProperty("java.home")`, then appending the equivalent of "/bin/java", using the local filesystem directory separators and executable name.  On Windows, this results in "\bin\java.exe".  Thus, the **spawned** Java command will use the full path to whatever Java launcher as the current **spawning** process used, wherever that Java installation happens to live on the computer.

This has worked well for some years... until now.

We got a bug report from a remote user, and we're having a hard time figuring out how in the world they've managed to get where they are.  The user in question is obviously running Java 8, but I don't know any additional useful details about their system.

They're reporting that the `ProcessBuilder#start()` call fails with this stacktrace:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_221\bin\java.exe" (in
directory "[the a_different_working_directory that was passed above]"): CreateProcess error=0, The operation completed successfully
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at [our own program stacktrace, not useful here]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=0, The operation completed successfully
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
    ... 9 more
```

*Cue the Windows "task failed successfully" image memes!*

We have many, many other users all successfully running the same software under Java 8, even under Windows 7.

Looking at the source for OpenJDK 8, the code for `ProcessImpl#create()` is basically a long chain of copying strings across the JNI boundary, then calling an internal `processCreate` function.  That function in turn comes down to

```
// jdk/src/windows/native/java/lang/ProcessImpl_md.c
// line 320 or so

if (!CreateProcessW(
    NULL,             /* executable name */
    (LPWSTR)pcmd,     /* command line */
    NULL,             /* process security attribute */
    NULL,             /* thread security attribute */
    TRUE,             /* inherits system handles */
    processFlag,      /* selected based on exe type */
    (LPVOID)penvBlock,/* environment block */
    (LPCWSTR)pdir,    /* change to the new current directory */
    &si,              /* (in)  startup information */
    &pi))             /* (out) process information */
{
    win32Error(env, L"CreateProcess");
} else {
// normal successful cleanup and return
```

The local `win32Error` routine allocates some character arrays for buffers, and then calls `GetLastError()`.  So there are **no other Win32 API calls** between returning from `CreateProcessW` and getting the latest error number.  (The OpenJDK folks generally know what they're doing, but I figured somebody would ask.)  After fetching the latest error number, it uses `FormatMessageW` and similar to build up the error message before throwing the `IOException` back across the JNI boundary.

What could `CreateProcessW` be doing to signal a failure without setting an error code?  And what can we do about it allllll the way out at the Java level with a `ProcessBuilder`?